# Highchart tooltip with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, tooltip

I'm trying to finish work from a sick colleague but my json knowledge is so poor I just can't seem to get this tooltip working properly.

The data to build up the points for a highchart is being written in json as:

```
"data": {
        "parties": [
            [ 48, 138, 130, 84, 82, 72, 65, 55, 40, -40]
        ]
    }
```

with each data point, I should be able to write some additional data. I found some other stackoverflows which has lead me to something that works for me to call the Mydata in the tooltip, except for: Mydata is not defined (in the json) yet.

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.myData + '</b>';
```

I've put up a fiddle where you can look into the complete json and javascript here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vmt66qb3/1/

I really can't seem to get it working without breaking things, I hope this is enough information as I can't provide a working link of the client but if you need more information, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your fiddle isn't working.Your myData should be inserted with series points. In your case :

```
 dataObject.y = value;
 dataObject.id = 'x-' + index;
 dataObject.myData = your data;
```

and in tooltip formatter function you can call it back as this.point.mydata;

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The fiddle is'nt working because it's just to show my complete json (in the css box) and js.

Can I be so impolite to ask for a more complete answer, though? As I am trying to put different myData for each point but I can't see how I should do this with the provided code: "dataObject.myData = your data;"

Correct me if mistaken but in this case "your data" would be showed at every point in a tooltip, I would like to have a different tooltip-text at each point. Thx again!

Comment: Exactly, you every point would have different valaes of mydata....while putting different values for x,id etc you have to put value for mydata as well (inside your loop )

Comment: Can you also please tell me how I put values for each point? if I add dataObject.myData = your data; it's just showing me "your data" at every point? Thanks!!

Comment: Could something like this work? 

if (dataObject.y === '40') {

                   dataObject.myData = 'text for point 40';
                }

Comment: it's not ofc, i'm such a noob at this :D

Comment: Each point should be an object, like {y:102,myData: 'content of tooltip'}